# Loading data into hive from windows client machine

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hive

I have successfully fetched data from hive from my hadoop cluster using eclipse from windows using the below statements.

```
Connection con =       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://10.10.234.229:10000/Pooja", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Pooja.src where id=10");
```

I tried the below statement:

```
stmt.executeQuery("load data local inpath 'file:d:/data.txt' into table Pooja.test1");
```

But its not working.

Comment: What's the error that you are getting? Which release of `Hive` are you using?

Comment: I am using hive 0.10. Trying to load data from windows using eclipse to hive in hadoop cluster on linux. Is the execute statement correct. I am getting error that file path doesnt exists. I think it is trying to find that path in cluster rather than my client machine.